# EnhancedList view rendered Problem

Tags: visualforce

I am having a problem when I try to render an `<apex:EnhancedList>`.

I have an `actionFunction` which calls a controller method to set a boolean value to true and rerender that `enhancedList`.

It keeps displaying Loading but does not load.

Below is the code.

```
   <apex:outputPanel id="enhancedActivityList">
          <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:enhancedList type="Activity" height="600" rendered="{!isEnahanceListEnabled }"  />
          </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

I have initialized a variable in the controller I set it to true when an icon is clicked using the `actionfunction` and rerender the `outputPanel`.

Comment: Does it work if you just put true instead of method result?

Comment: Yes, it works if it is set manually.

Comment: public Boolean isEnahanceListEnabled { get { return true; } } <== does this work?

Comment: Do you follow this statement for enhancedList => "Ext JS versions less than 3 should not be included on pages that use this component."

Comment: Have you tried the same code but with other object, let's say Account?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "Ext JS versions"

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm

Comment: I have tried without any Ext JS also with other object but no hope it is not working.  Seems an SF bug

Comment: I'll try with mine page. I have a page with enhancedList. I'll put the same code as you and try it. Oh, BTW, what version of VF page are you using? Try to reduce the version and remove Ext JS from your page.

Comment: Hi, reduce the version but has the same result. Do you have any specific version in mind with which I need to test with? Presently its 29 version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too old to be of continued value to the community, barring an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting...

It works for me if I don't have:

```
  <script>

    function f1() {}
    window.onload = f1();

  </script>
```

And if comment out window.onload = f1(); it appears in normal way.
I'm using jQuery on my page.

I suppose enhanceList going crazy with JavaScript.

I don't use enhancedList. I don't remember why. I use apex:ListViews instead.

Comment: @user3373904 So, what was the problem? If you solve your problem, please post your own answer on your own question ;-)

Comment: Could not solve